# Using <include> tag with ?attr/myAttr

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-attributes

I'm trying to include different layouts in my View depending on the parent `Theme`.

Following the idea:

**attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="themeLayout" format="reference" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="themeLayout">@layout/layout_a</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeSecond" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="themeLayout">@layout/layout_b</item>
</style>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="?attr/themeLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the Code above I'll get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.package/com.my.package.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: You must specifiy a valid layout reference. The layout ID ?attr/themeLayout is not valid.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: You must specifiy a valid layout reference. The layout ID ?attr/themeLayout is not valid.
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:866)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to do this at all?

**Note #1:** I set the `Theme` of my `MainActivity` to `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

**Note #2:** In the Design-View of the Layout Editor everything works as expected. If I switch the Theme, the include gets updated properly.
See the following Screenshots as well:

[image: preview design tab android studio]

Comment: Never thought on doing this way... hope somebody answers because it is a cool problem you´ve found

Comment: This way you can not include layout base on theme may be have to create  and load theme base layout.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I'm not sure what you're trying to say. It think the weird part is that the Layout-Editor can resolve the attribute, but the Code at runtime isn't able to do so as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible but I really like the idea. I have tracked the flow of `LayoutInflater` and it requieres the `layout` attribute to be [`TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#TYPE_REFERENCE) which means `?attr` is not allowed. They even left a comment in the method to explain.

> ```
> public int getAttributeResourceValue(int idx, int defaultValue) {
>     int t = nativeGetAttributeDataType(mParseState, idx);
>     // Note: don't attempt to convert any other types, because
>     // we want to count on aapt doing the conversion for us.
>     if (t == TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE) {
>         return nativeGetAttributeData(mParseState, idx);
>     }
>     return defaultValue;
> }
> ```
>
> android.content.res.XmlBlock.java:385

Basically you have done nothing wrong -- the inflation in Preview works differently which caused the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. There's just one more thing I don't get: What is `format="reference"` if not a `TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE`?

Comment: That only tells you that `<item name="themeLayout">` has to be of `TYPE_REFERENCE`. If you parse the layout XML and find a `?attr/themeLayout` it is a `TYPE_ATTRIBUTE`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for the explanation. Luckily [reVerse' approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30265925/4126219) works for me and it's nearly similiar to the `<include />` tag stuff

Answer (score 4):

Since [Lamorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4584675/lamorak) explained everything in detail in his ["in-depth" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30261745/982852) I guess it's save to say that there isn't any solution with the `<include />` tag for your problem.
So following a different approach that worked in my test project:

**#1 - Replace** `<include />` **with** `<ViewStub />`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/myStub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/myInflatedStub"
        android:layout="?attr/themeLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**#2 - Inflate the ViewStub**

```
ViewStub myStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.myStub);
myStub.inflate();
```

Any drawbacks with this method? Well you won't see the ViewStub-Layout in your Design-Tab and using the `<merge />` tag won't work.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found this problem-"*has been fixed in Android23*. But bellows, exception will be thrown.